# C#-MySQL Pass Null Paratmer To Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Since MySQL doesn't allow default values for parameters, i have been trying to send Null values from the code but unfortunately nothing is working.

I have read many questions here and i know that there is a workaround by sending empty string and then doing an if-statement in the stored procedure.

My question is, isn't there anyway i could send a value from C# that MySql could interpret as a null value. Reason i am asking this cause i am using `IS NULL` checks which is already implemented in all of sp's becuase i have migrated from MSSQL to MySQL.

I have tried regular `null` and `DBNull.Value` but i keep getting an `Unhandled type encountered` exception.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `User_Check_Avialability`(  
   IN Username NVARCHAR(50),
   IN Email NVARCHAR(50)
    )

BEGIN   
    SELECT  COUNT(*) AS NumberOfUsers
    FROM    User
    WHERE   (( User.Username = Username OR Username IS NULL ) AND ( User.Email = Email OR Email IS NULL ));

END
```

Here is my code:

```
    try
{
    using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            mySqlCommand.Connection = mySqlConnection;
            mySqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            mySqlCommand.CommandText = "User_Check_Avialability";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objUsers.Username))
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", objUsers.Username);
            else
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", DBNull.Value); //Also tried null                      

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objUsers.Email))
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", objUsers.Email);
            else
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", DBNull.Value); //Also tried null

//Also tried
mySqlCommand.Parameters["Username"].IsNullable = true;
mySqlCommand.Parameters["Email"].IsNullable = true;

            bool isAvailable = false;

            mySqlConnection.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (!mySqlDataReader.HasRows)
                    isAvailable = true;
                else
                {
                    while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        if (int.Parse(mySqlDataReader["NumberOfUsers"].ToString()) == 0)
                            isAvailable = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return isAvailable;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: sp posted please. 5 lines

Comment: Have you tried using `isNullable` parameter? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommandmembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlparameter

Comment: @shree.pat18, is there any special way to do it. I tried both null & DBNull.Value along with setting parameters to IsNullable but same exception occurs.

Comment: Can you share the C# code as well? I can't test myself, but looking at the code may help others to answer also.

Comment: Did you try using `Add` instead of `AddWithValue`? That would let you set the type of parameter, which I think is what's missing when using `AddWithValue`.

Comment: It worked!!!!. Could you please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the valuable comments, the solution is that you should specify the type of the parameter and make it `Nullable`.

Here is the sample code:

```
                    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("Username", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    mySqlCommand.Parameters["Username"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                    mySqlCommand.Parameters["Username"].IsNullable = true;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objUsers.Name))
                        mySqlCommand.Parameters["Username"].Value = objUsers.Name;
```

As you can see here, even if you don't pass a null value there will be no problem because the parameter is already added and if there is no value then it will be null.